# Is there a way to get rid of loop for layers in a neural network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

I have being learning about deep neural networks and how the increase in hidden layers give better results. but the problem that i found was we usually get rid of loops in calculations by using matrices. Is there any way to remove the for loop which loop though the layers in forward and backward propagation?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: It is actually not an exact problem. I could not find a solution anywhere, how that loop can be removed. So was wondering whether it is possible...

Comment: You generally aren't "removing" loops when you express calculations with matrices, you are just hiding them. You can probably hide the back-propagation in an accumulate

Comment: What is accumulate and how can it help? I haven't heard of this term.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to remove the for loops? What advantage do you think it will give your solution?

Comment: Are you trying to parallelize the calculation?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Won't It Speed up the forward and backward propagations

Comment: @FrankPuffer Something Like that. So is there a way

Comment: Matrices are not a replacement for loops, they just make the loops implicit. Except for the parallelization offered by modern hardware, matrix elements are still processed in loops. Deep nn frameworks typically utilize matrices a lot already to achieve their performance.

Comment: [accumulate in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) or [aggregate in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [fold in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold) are all functions meaning "combine all the elements of this sequence, via this operation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that what you actually want to do is calculate the layers in parallel (at the same time). In general that is not possible because in forward propagation you need the output of the previous layer(s) to calculate a given layer. For backpropagation the dependency is reversed.

But when you look at typical network architectures, there are not more than a few hundred layers, typically much less. On the other hand each layer can have many thousands of weights.

Therefore you can save much more time by running the calculations within each layer in parallel and that is not an issue because they are independent from each other.